# How to create multible labels non-ovelaped in CartoDB?

Tags: labeling, carto, visualisation

I'm trying to make a map pointing the cities I've visited for work, in each city I've visited more than one place. Those places are my labels, bur they are overlapped. If I choose label overlap = false, only one label shows, but I need all of them to appear.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you could show them only in lower zoom levels

Answer (score 1):

You will need to incorporate some advanced labeling CartoCSS to make this happen.  MapBox has a [good guide here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/labels-advanced/) that should get you started and may even solve it for you.  Are you trying to label businesses you've been to or suburbs?  If so, you can add those in [OpenStreetMap](http://osm.org) and then use an OSM basemap for your map.